# What exactly happens in a power-fail interrupt?

Tags: operating-system, interrupt

I came across the term "power-fail interrupt" on Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_priority_level).

Since power-failure occurs instantly, what is the use of this interrupt? By the time the computer realizes it has encountered a power-failure, it'll be switched off! What's the point of it? Also, this interrupt is given the highest priority.

Have I misunderstood the term "power-fail"?

Comment: Batteries. Or more commonly used in embedded systems - capacitors.

Comment: @slebetman are you defining the term "power-fail"?

Comment: Power fail means that the mains power has failed. Don't think laptops. Think servers with UPS.

Comment: On a lot of embedded systems such as sim cards (yes, sim cards are computers) the hardware needs to save data when power is removed. Saving data takes 1/100 or a second. A small capacitor can still provide enough power to the CPU for 1/10 of a second after power failure. That's plenty of time to shut down gracefully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a power failure, the computer can remain on life support using reserve power (such as a battery).

The article you quote talks specifically about the VAX architecture. The way the power-fail interrupt works there is [as follows](http://odl.sysworks.biz/disk$cddoc04jan11/decw$book/aa-jm81e-01__a01_b2.p101.decw$book):

> Once a power-failure interrupt has been posted, the processor has
>   approximately 4 milliseconds before power is shut down.

Thus the interrupt handler has four milliseconds to do its thing.

Comment: Note that while the term in the article refers to VAXen, power fail interrupts are still with us on server hardware - it's what UPS systems use to signal that the OS should start shutting down.

Comment: On old UPSes that communicate via serial port it really was a hardware interrupt via the CTS pin. On more modern USB equipped UPSes it's a virtual software interrupt via the USB bus.